# Получить текущую директорию, в командной строке на C#. .NET 5

Tags: c#, .net, cmd, .net-5

Я хочу написать CLI на C#. То есть, юзер должен запускать моё приложение через командную строку. Для того, чтобы выполнить мою задачу, мне нужно получить директорию, в которой сейчас находится юзер в командной строке.

Comment: Поищите по названию Рабочая папка или working directory.

Comment: Вот это вроде Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), ответом не пишу, тк проверить пока не на чем.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ @tym32167 полностью верный. Я проверил.

> Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()

Единственное что стоит добавить, это

```
using System.IO;
```